# How to fix Library not loaded: @rpath/libssl.1.1.dylib when compiling with py2app?

Tags: python-3.x, macos, py2app

Environment:

Mac OS X Catalina 10.15.6
Python 8

Hi,
I try to compile my python code with py2app.
Here is my setup.py:

```
"""
This is a setup.py script generated by py2applet

Usage:
    python setup.py py2app
"""

from setuptools import setup

APP = ['MyApp.py']
APP_NAME = "MyApp"
DATA_FILES = [ 'necessary_files/create_db.sql',
                    'necessary_files/fra.traineddata',
                    'necessary_files/ui.txt',
                    'MyApp_Install.sh',
                    'necessary_files/assets',
                    'necessary_files/cgi',
                    'necessary_files/selenium',
                    'ui/']
OPTIONS = {
    'iconfile': 'MyApp_icon.icns',
    'packages': ['requests', 'selenium'],
    'plist': {
        'CFBundleName': APP_NAME,
        'CFBundleDisplayName': APP_NAME,
        'CFBundleGetInfoString': "Marketing Bot",
        'CFBundleIdentifier': "com.cff.MyApp",
        'CFBundleVersion': "0.0.2",
        'CFBundleShortVersionString': "0.0.2",
        'NSHumanReadableCopyright': u"Copyright © 2020, CFF, All Rights Reserved"}
        }

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

When compilation is done, I run my app with this command in terminal in order to see error and I get this:

```
/Users/gauthierbtz/Dropbox/cff/Python/MyApp_0002_FINAL/dist/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp ; exit;
(base) gauthierbtz@MacBook-de-Gauthier ~ % /Users/gauthierbtz/Dropbox/cff/Python/MyApp_0002_FINAL/dist/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp ; exit;
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/gauthierbtz/Dropbox/cff/Python/MyApp_0002_FINAL/dist/MyApp.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 115, in <module>
    _run()
  File "/Users/gauthierbtz/Dropbox/cff/Python/MyApp_0002_FINAL/dist/MyApp.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 84, in _run
    exec(compile(source, path, "exec"), globals(), globals())
  File "/Users/gauthierbtz/Dropbox/cff/Python/MyApp_0002_FINAL/dist/MyApp.app/Contents/Resources/MyApp.py", line 29, in <module>
    import mymodules
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "mymodules.pyc", line 5, in <module>
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "ssl.pyc", line 98, in <module>
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/gauthierbtz/Dropbox/cff/Python/MyApp_0002_FINAL/dist/MyApp.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_ssl.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libssl.1.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/gauthierbtz/Dropbox/cff/Python/MyApp_0002_FINAL/dist/MyApp.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_ssl.so
  Reason: image not found
2020-09-12 22:15:58.769 MyApp[81463:1290389] MyApp Error
```

So I searched for solution in Google and tried some stuff.

I reinstall openssl with command "brew reinstall openssl"

I added this in my .zshrc file:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl\@1.1/bin:$PATH"
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl\@1.1/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl\@1.1/include"
```

I restart my terminal.

I typed these lines in my terminal:

```
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl\@1.1/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl\@1.1/include"
```

And I still get the same error message. I don't know what else to do.

I uploaded here the logs of the compilation if it can help. I didn't see anything weird:
https://github.com/gauthierbuttez/public/blob/master/logs_py2app.txt

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled over the same issue that a shared library could be linked against during the linker stage of building an executable but not be found at runtime.  The solution was in my case to just tell dyld to look for the shared library in the right path when I run my program:

```
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:/PATH_TO/YOUR_/DYLIB_FILE Run_me
```

I hope that this will work for you, too.